# How many steps of bisection method are needed to obtain certain error

Tags: convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, computer-science

> If $a = 0.1$ and $b = 1.0$, how many steps of the bisection method are
>       needed to determine the root with an error of at most $1/2 × 10^{−8}$ ?

How can I calculate this is I have no function to determine the value of f(c)?

Comment: The interval size reduction rule is independent of the function values, you needn't know $f$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ and $b_n$ be the left and right endpoints of the interval after $n\geq 0$ steps of bisection, where initially, $a_0 = a = 0.1$ and $b_0 = b = 1$. Since the interval width is halved after each step, it follows that $b_n - a_n = (b-a)/2^n = 0.9/2^n$. Now suppose you take the midpoint of $[a_n,b_n]$ as your approximation to the true root $x$. Then,

$$
\left|x - \frac{a_n +b_n}{2}\right| \leq \frac{b_n - a_n}{2} \leq \frac{0.9}{2^{n+1}}
$$

Thus, in order for the error to be at most $1/2\times 10^{-8}$ it will take at least

$$
n \geq \lceil\log_2(1.8\times 10^8) - 1\rceil = 27
$$

steps of bisection.

Answer (score 0):

Bisection reduces the length of the active interval by half in every step.

The error can be maximally as big as the last active interval.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to calculate number of steps needed to obtained certain error by using following formula:

$$n \geq 1.443 \ln \left(\frac{b_1 - a_1}{e}\right)$$

where $n =$ Number of steps needed, $e=$ Error, $a_1$ and $b_1=$ Limits of an interval

For above example,
$$n \geq 1.443 \ln \left(\frac{1 - 0.1}{0.5 \cdot 10^{-8}}\right) = 27 \text{ steps}$$

Comment: @SteamyRoot Thanks for editing!